# Tag search text box hidden by default

Tags: feature-request, search, ios-app

When searching for tags would it be possible to have the search text box visible by default.

I don't think I should have to scroll up to reveal the search text box when I haven't scrolled down yet.

Also I don't think I should have to scroll all the way to the top to find the search text box. Like using chrome et al I want the search bar to appear whenever I scroll up.

Answer (score 2):

Search field for tags (as well as questions and users, for that matter) are now visible by default.

I'm not marking this as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) yet now to consider the second part of your request a little further.